# How do I add each element of a list to a separate column In a Data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a list to a Data frame. Converting a list to a Data frame is simple, but the problem is it creates a single column for all the values in a data Frame. But I want to assign each element in the list to a different column in a Data Frame

Suppose Following is my list

```
val ListofElements = List(2.0,5.0,3.0)
```

I want to convert this list to a data frame such that 2.0 is assigned to "firstcolumn", similarly 5.0 to "SecondColumn, and 3.0 to "ThirdColumn"
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A list of tuples will behave the way you want want `List((2.0,5.0,3.0)).toDF("first", "second", "third")`. It's a bit trickier if you need to automate this conversion with any number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`.toDF`()** method with **`List[(row),(row)]`**

```
sc.parallelize(List(2.0,5.0,3.0) match{case List(a,b,c) => List((a,b,c))}).toDF("firstcolumn","SecondColumn","ThirdColumn").show()
//+-----------+------------+-----------+
//|firstcolumn|SecondColumn|ThirdColumn|
//+-----------+------------+-----------+
//|        2.0|         5.0|        3.0|
//+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `SparkSession` instance is named `spark`, you can first `import spark.implicits._`, and then do:

```
> val df = Seq((2.0,5.0,3.0)).toDF("firstcolumn","SecondColumn","ThirdColumn")
> df.show()

+-----------+------------+-----------+
|firstcolumn|SecondColumn|ThirdColumn|
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|        2.0|         5.0|        3.0|
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Notice that your earlier `List` has now been converted into a `Seq` of `Tuple3` objects..